# Comparing two different Regression Models using the same set of Independent Variables

Tags: regression, anova, model, aic

I'm currently working on the same set of independent variables to explain FDI across different time series data; hence, I'll like to know if there is a statistical tool that tells which of the model best explains FDI.

Comment: where FDI means...

Comment: Foreign Direct Investment